# cannot touch `/var/log/mysqld.log': Permission denied

Tags: mysql, logging, centos, permission-denied

i have reinstalled mysql server in cent OS RHEL5.5 , Im getting the following error

```
touch: cannot touch `/var/log/mysqld.log': Permission denied

chown: changing ownership of `/var/log/mysqld.log': Operation not permitted

chmod: changing permissions of `/var/log/mysqld.log': Operation not permitted

MySQL Daemon failed to start.

Starting mysqld:                                           [FAILED]
```

I have checked the permissions for log files , its having correct permissions as mysql user

```
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql   5931 Mar  9 04:36 mysqld.log
```

Please let me know the issue on this and how to solve it.

Thanks

Comment: you are running mysql with user `mysql`? which permissions has the directory `/var/log`?

Comment: try using chmod 660 mysqld.log once, using root permissions

Comment: chmod: changing permissions of `/var/log/mysqld.log': Operation not permitted

Comment: no as root user @Jens

Comment: What is the output of `whoami`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok. I have solved the issue,

$ /usr/libexec/mysqld --skip-grant &

[1] 5388

InnoDB: Error: log file ./ib_logfile0 is of different size 0 50331648 bytes

InnoDB: than specified in the .cnf file 0 5242880 bytes!
150312 10:03:28 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.0.95'  socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  Source distribution

$ rm -rf /var/lib/mysql/ib_logfile0

$ rm -rf /var/lib/mysql/ib_logfile1

$ ls -l /var/lib/mysql

i have removed the log files and restart the mysql server.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The workaround is:

```
$ sudo touch /var/log/mysqld.log
$ sudo chown mysql:mysql /var/log/mysqld.log
$ sudo chcon system_u:object_r:mysqld_log_t:s0 /var/log/mysqld.log
```

Answer (score 1):

selinux was enforcing, disabled it and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this happened to me after downgrading an AWS EC2 instance. The error was as follows:

```
$ service mysqld start
touch: cannot touch ‘/var/log/mysqld.log’: Permission denied
chown: changing ownership of ‘/var/log/mysqld.log’: Operation not permitted
chmod: changing permissions of ‘/var/log/mysqld.log’: Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of ‘/var/lib/mysql’: Operation not permitted
chmod: changing permissions of ‘/var/lib/mysql’: Operation not permitted
MySQL Daemon failed to start.
Starting mysqld:                                           [FAILED]
```

Turns out the issue was the new downgraded VM didn't have enough memory as MySQL was trying to reserve.

Updating the value reserved for InnoDB on `etc/my.cnf` solved the issue:

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size=4G
```

No other changes on the file system permissions were needed.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, there is problem with ubuntu apparmor.

Solution:

Edit mysqld profiles (usually in /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld) and make sure you have:

```
/var/log/mysqld.log rw,

systemctl reload apparmor

touch /var/log/mysqld.log

chown mysql:mysql /var/log/mysqld.log

chmod 0644 /var/log/mysqld.log

systemctl restart mysql
```