# percona-server:mysqld.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE

Tags: mysql, percona

I have installed percona-server on my arch linux, it seems that by default it fails to start. It is local and I dont intend to use it elsewhere.
I've tried the followings:
1-https://stackoverflow.com/a/29006954
since it fails and tells me to refer to `systemctl` and `journalctl` , Here's the
output by `sytemctl status mysqld.service`

```
    mysqld.service - MySQL Server
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/mysqld.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2021-12-17 01:39:11 +0330; 7s ago
       Docs: man:mysqld(8)
             http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/en/using-systemd.html
    Process: 137811 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/mysqld_pre_systemd (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 137838 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mysqld $MYSQLD_OPTS (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 137838 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
     Status: "Data Dictionary upgrade from MySQL 5.7 in progress"
        CPU: 3.772s
```

output by `journalctl -xeu mysqld.service`

```
Support: https://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
 A start job for unit mysqld.service has begun execution.
 The job identifier is 3335.
Dec 17 01:39:11 a31557g systemd[1]: mysqld.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
 Subject: Unit process exited
 Defined-By: systemd
 Support: https://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
 
 An ExecStart= process belonging to unit mysqld.service has exited.
 
 The process' exit code is 'exited' and its exit status is 1.
Dec 17 01:39:11 a31557g systemd[1]: mysqld.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
 Subject: Unit failed
 Defined-By: systemd
 Support: https://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
 
 The unit mysqld.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'exit-code'.
Dec 17 01:39:11 a31557g systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Server.
 Subject: A start job for unit mysqld.service has failed Defined-By: systemd
Support: https://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel  A start job for unit mysqld.service has finished with a failure. 
 The job identifier is 3335 and the job result is failed.
```

if I use tail:

```
$ sudo tail -f /var/log/mysqld.log


021-12-16T22:09:10.699830Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010075] [Server] No existing UUID has been found, so we assume that this is the first time that this server has been started. Generating a new UUID: cbc20bf1-5ebc-11ec-88cf-d8f3bc3b346b.
2021-12-16T22:09:10.745941Z 1 [System] [MY-011012] [Server] Starting upgrade of data directory.
2021-12-16T22:09:10.746104Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2021-12-16T22:09:10.844571Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012224] [InnoDB] Tablespace flags are invalid in datafile: ./ibdata1, Space ID:0, Flags: 21. Please refer to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-troubleshooting-datadict.html for how to resolve the issue.
2021-12-16T22:09:10.844732Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012237] [InnoDB] Corrupted page [page id: space=0, page number=0] of datafile './ibdata1' could not be found in the doublewrite buffer.
2021-12-16T22:09:10.844870Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012930] [InnoDB] Plugin initialization aborted with error Data structure corruption.
2021-12-16T22:09:11.812981Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-011013] [Server] Failed to initialize DD Storage Engine.
2021-12-16T22:09:11.813303Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010020] [Server] Data Dictionary initialization failed.
2021-12-16T22:09:11.813435Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2021-12-16T22:09:11.813732Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/bin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.26-16)  Source distribution.
```

other tried answers:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/33392625

output:

```
chcon: failed to change context of '/var/log/mysqld.log' to ‘system_u:object_r:mysqld_log_t:s0’: Operation not supported
```

and a lot of other combinations of such

there must be some stupid detail that Im missing, makes wanna go back to Windows and use MySql server and SSMS

I'm seriously tired and don't know what else to do,I seriously need this,haven't slept properly for two days . HELP!

Comment: use a backup and restore the databse

Comment: There is no backup to be made since it's the first time and it won't even start. I wanted to use percona since it's a drop in replacemnet of mysql and can be used with mysql workbench as themselves mentioned it.. I guess I have to try my luck with mariadb if I can't fix percona, or switch to windows altogeher(again)

Comment: There are some checks and recovery options search recovery mode and I create the number. I still wonder how you got there  with a new system else delete everything and start from scratch and make backup on every step of the way

Comment: see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-recovery.html